# several actions inside If condition

Tags: assignment

Trying to write code with If, if it is correct to perform a number of actions.
I am a beginner user in mathematica and not sure the form of writing are correct.

What I'm asking in simple, this is the template for If:
If[condition,t,f]

when the condition is true, I want it do several actions, so I  writer:
If[condition,t1 && t2 && t3,f]

In this case it does not work for me, when I write If within If, there is another way to perform a several actions instead use && symbol?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You can combine several "actions" (expressions) into a single [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) by using semicolon ``;``. For example: ``If[x > 3, Print["x>3"]; y = 5; z = 1, Print["x<3"]; y = -1; z = 4]``

Comment: Lists can be good alternatives to compound expressions.  Consider this expression, for example, `{y, z} = If[x > 3, {5, 1}, {-1, 4}]`.  This expression uses `If` to make different assignments $y$ and $z$ depending on the value of $x>3$.